# How can I use the home, end, page-up, page-down keys on Solaris via PuTTY?

Tags: unix, solaris, putty, keyboard, keys

I love the shortcuts home, end, page-up, page-down, but I am unable to use them via PuTTY on Solaris servers.

```
Windows PuTTY => Linux desktop via SSH, works fine.
Windows PuTTY => Solaris server, shortcuts keys problems.
Windows PuTTY => Linux VM => Solaris server, shortcuts keys problems.
Linux desktop => Solaris server, works fine.
```

What is the reasons that these keys are not working and how can I make them work, without changing something on each individual Solaris server?

Answer (score 2):

Since you didn't specify what you want the keys to do, I'm assuming that you want to do the following;

**Page-up:** scroll the terminal up a page

**Page-Down:** Scroll the terminal down a page

**Home:** Move the cursor to the beginning of the commandline

**End:** Move the cursor to the end of the commandline

The page-up/down keys will work in PuTTY regardless of OS if you just hold the Shift key.
Shift+PgUp will scroll the PuTTY window up a page.

The Home and End keys require a terminfo change (various kinds will work), and are typically dependent on what type of shell you are using (sh, ksh, bash, and so forth).

Using your examples above, please check your TERM setting (`echo $TERM`) and what shell you are using (`ps` or `echo $SHELL`).

For more info, there's [this question/answer on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/94436/how-to-configure-putty-so-that-home-end-pgup-pgdn-work-properly-in-bash).